# How to convert Boolean value to Yes/No while rendering the flexigrid table

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

Here is how i am implementing flexigrid

```
$('.mytable').flexigrid({
    url: '<c:url value="/callController"/>',
    dataType: 'json',
    colModel : [
        {display: 'ID', name : 'id', width : 40, sortable : true, align: 'right'},
        {display: 'Name', name : 'name', width : 150, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
        {display: 'Checkbox checked', name : 'checked', width : 150, sortable : false, align: 'left' }
        ],              
    sortname: "id",
    sortorder: "asc",
    usepager: true,
    title: false,
    useRp: false,
    rp: 15,
    showTableToggleBtn: false,
    showToggleBtn: false,
            singleSelect: true,
            striped: true,
    height: 200,
    width: 'auto'
});
```

If you see the third column, the value for 'checked' is returning as true/false (Boolean), but i want to display it as Yes/No on the table.

Is there any way to convert this true/false value to Yes/No while rendering the table?

Platform: Java, SpringMVC, JQuery

Comment: `Yes/No` is still Boolean, and remember: you can do whatever you want to any boolean with conditionals. That's what they're for. `if (boolean-is-true) { // do something } else { //do something else }`

Comment: Thanks for your response, where do i need to put these conditions to convert the values while rendering the table...

Comment: The only place I see the word 'checked' in the code you posted is inside a string, so I have no idea what you mean by 'the value of checked', or why you think it is a boolean.

Comment: the call to the service @ url = '<c:url value="/callController"/>' will return a object, and this object has a variable with name 'checked' and its type is boolean (returns true/false).

Comment: I don't know anything about flexigrid, but by looking at it I suppose you would change `{display: 'Checkbox checked', ...` with `{display: (this.checked)? 'yes': 'no', ...` or something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can supply a "preProcess" callback function to alter/format the data returned by the ajax call before it is displayed:

```
preProcess: function(data) {
    $.each(data.rows, function(i, row) {
        row.checked = row.checked ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    });
    return data;
},
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uVADL/2/)

---

Note: I don't really see where the "preProcess" callback is documented other than the following note on the [Flexigrid project page](http://code.google.com/p/flexigrid/):

> New preProcess API, allows you to modify or process data sent by
>   server before passing it to Flexigrid, allowing you to use your own
>   JSON format for example.

It seems, however, to work pretty much like the "dataFilter" callback of the [jQuery `.ajax` function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Yay!!! That worked with a small correction, it should be row.cell.checked instead of row.checked. Thank you so much...